# Node Join but master only show master node on kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flannel

I have one master and two node to build `kubernetes` cluster. Both node successfully join the master (according to console log). But, when I run `kubectl get nodes`, which is show master only.

Here `ip a` on master

[image]

I run as below to init the cluster

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.8 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

The cluster is successfully started and I apply `flannel`.

[image]

Node Join to Master

[image]

And I check `nodes` and all of `pods`

[image]

Is there any problem here? Even if `Node` join to successfully to cluster, which is only show `master`

Is it correct for `--pod-network-cidr` ?

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.8 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

**update**

`systemctl status kubelet` on master

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-02-19 02:10:31 EST; 3min 20s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 2099 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 37.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─2099 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs -...

Feb 19 02:13:48 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:48.423482    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e5b3349f-3415-11e9-9...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:48 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:48.423758    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "etcd-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e5b30354-3415-11e9-9138-080027...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:48 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:48.423926    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e5b31fd5-3415-11e9-9...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:48 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:48.424101    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e5b32acb-34...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:50 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:50.431977    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e6e55cb5-3415-11e9-9...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:50 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:50.432249    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e6e56f52-3415-11e9-9...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:50 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:50.432406    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e6e59401-34...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:50 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:50.432560    2099 kubelet.go:1647] Deleting mirror pod "etcd-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(e6e5802e-3415-11e9-9138-080027...t is outdated
Feb 19 02:13:51 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: W0219 02:13:51.977049    2099 cni.go:203] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 19 02:13:51 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2099]: E0219 02:13:51.977207    2099 kubelet.go:2192] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady messa...uninitialized
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

`journalctl -u kubelet` on master

```
[root@localhost ~]# journalctl -u kubelet
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-19 01:31:20 EST, end at Tue 2019-02-19 02:14:27 EST. --
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13181]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kuberne
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13181]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kuberne
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13181]: F0219 01:39:11.716907   13181 server.go:244] unable to load client CA file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:39:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:39:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:39:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:39:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kuberne
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kuberne
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.050655   13189 server.go:407] Version: v1.13.3
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.050858   13189 plugins.go:103] No cloud provider specified.
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.065072   13189 certificate_manager.go:348] Failed while requesting a signed certificate from the master: cannot create certificate signin
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.110331   13189 server.go:666] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.110567   13189 container_manager_linux.go:248] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: []
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.110585   13189 container_manager_linux.go:253] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroups
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.110663   13189 container_manager_linux.go:272] Creating device plugin manager: true
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.110721   13189 state_mem.go:36] [cpumanager] initializing new in-memory state store
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.111976   13189 kubelet.go:281] Adding pod path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.112038   13189 kubelet.go:306] Watching apiserver
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.114437   13189 client.go:75] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.114454   13189 client.go:104] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.115604   13189 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:453: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.56.8:6443/api
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.115643   13189 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:444: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.56.8:6443/
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.115721   13189 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.56.8:6
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: W0219 01:39:22.116751   13189 docker_service.go:540] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.116765   13189 docker_service.go:236] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: W0219 01:39:22.116832   13189 cni.go:203] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: W0219 01:39:22.119472   13189 cni.go:203] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.119494   13189 docker_service.go:251] Docker cri networking managed by cni
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.139202   13189 docker_service.go:256] Docker Info: &{ID:ROIM:X2IR:DVOT:SQNQ:Z2F6:LH72:VGRC:FSH4:YMBJ:SJWP:RF4S:JY45 Containers:0 Containe
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.139261   13189 docker_service.go:269] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.163372   13189 kuberuntime_manager.go:198] Container runtime docker initialized, version: 18.09.2, apiVersion: 1.39.0
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.167199   13189 server.go:999] Started kubelet
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.167526   13189 kubelet.go:1308] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imag
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.167913   13189 fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.167935   13189 status_manager.go:152] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.167944   13189 kubelet.go:1829] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.167954   13189 kubelet.go:1846] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet PLEG is not hea
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.168027   13189 server.go:137] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.168439   13189 server.go:333] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.169114   13189 volume_manager.go:248] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.169500   13189 event.go:212] Unable to write event: 'Post https://192.168.56.8:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 192.168.56
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.169922   13189 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:130] Desired state populator starts to run
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: W0219 01:39:22.171070   13189 cni.go:203] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.171245   13189 kubelet.go:2192] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: netw
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.269826   13189 kubelet.go:2266] node "localhost.localdomain" not found
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.269846   13189 kubelet.go:1846] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet]
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.269867   13189 kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.272256   13189 kubelet_node_status.go:72] Attempting to register node localhost.localdomain
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: E0219 01:39:22.272472   13189 kubelet_node_status.go:94] Unable to register node "localhost.localdomain" with API server: Post https://192.168.56.8:6443
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.277225   13189 kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.278536   13189 cpu_manager.go:155] [cpumanager] starting with none policy
Feb 19 01:39:22 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13189]: I0219 01:39:22.278544   13189 cpu_manager.go:156] [cpumanager] reconciling every 10s
```

status on node

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-02-19 02:13:23 EST; 5min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 14859 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 16
   Memory: 36.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─14859 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs ...

Feb 19 02:18:25 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:25.598922   14859 generic.go:277] PLEG: pod kube-proxy-4z575/kube-system failed reinspection: rpc error: code = Unknown desc...alid argument
Feb 19 02:18:26 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:26.602125   14859 kuberuntime_manager.go:857] PodSandboxStatus of sandbox "2d9acc379432bdae0c9de5e6d99d26b8ea6e450a19767bd231778febef9aff...
Feb 19 02:18:26 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:26.602146   14859 generic.go:247] PLEG: Ignoring events for pod kube-proxy-4z575/kube-system: rpc error: code = Unknown desc...alid argument
Feb 19 02:18:26 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:26.603365   14859 kuberuntime_manager.go:857] PodSandboxStatus of sandbox "2d9acc379432bdae0c9de5e6d99d26b8ea6e450a19767bd231778febef9aff...
Feb 19 02:18:26 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:26.603385   14859 generic.go:277] PLEG: pod kube-proxy-4z575/kube-system failed reinspection: rpc error: code = Unknown desc...alid argument
Feb 19 02:18:27 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:27.606248   14859 kuberuntime_manager.go:857] PodSandboxStatus of sandbox "2d9acc379432bdae0c9de5e6d99d26b8ea6e450a19767bd231778febef9aff...
Feb 19 02:18:27 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:27.606270   14859 generic.go:247] PLEG: Ignoring events for pod kube-proxy-4z575/kube-system: rpc error: code = Unknown desc...alid argument
Feb 19 02:18:27 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:27.607863   14859 kuberuntime_manager.go:857] PodSandboxStatus of sandbox "2d9acc379432bdae0c9de5e6d99d26b8ea6e450a19767bd231778febef9aff...
Feb 19 02:18:27 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:27.607880   14859 generic.go:277] PLEG: pod kube-proxy-4z575/kube-system failed reinspection: rpc error: code = Unknown desc...alid argument
Feb 19 02:18:27 localhost.localdomain kubelet[14859]: E0219 02:18:27.809433   14859 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 84186094-3415-11e9-9138-080027621cd9 ("kube-proxy-4z575_kube-system(84186094-3415...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@localhost ~]# journalctl -u kubelet
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-19 01:31:23 EST, end at Tue 2019-02-19 02:19:06 EST. --
Feb 19 01:31:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:31:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2802]: F0219 01:31:31.353952    2802 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/
Feb 19 01:31:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:31:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:31:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain kubelet[7337]: F0219 01:31:41.829265    7337 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:31:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain kubelet[11899]: F0219 01:31:52.188858   11899 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:31:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13110]: F0219 01:32:02.524046   13110 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:32:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13117]: F0219 01:32:12.854182   13117 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:32:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13124]: F0219 01:32:23.098681   13124 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:32:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13132]: F0219 01:32:33.350274   13132 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:32:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13140]: F0219 01:32:43.602227   13140 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 01:32:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Feb 19 01:32:53 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 19 01:32:53 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
```

Comment: Please also share the kubelet status and logs of the worker node, using `systemctl status kubelet` and 'journalctl -u kubelet`

Comment: @PrafullLadha, I update my question as your suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the node hostname to something else rather than localhost, as kubelet resolves based on hostname and it can't be localhost. The way you can do it in kubeadm is using `--node-name` parameter.

The `--node-name` parameter doesn't work alone, you need to provide the `--hostname-override` option in kubelete confs. Then only it will work

So, your kubelet extra args(`KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS`) at `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` should be `--hostname-override=<name>`. In addition to that while running init the cluster it should be:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.8 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --node-name=<name>
```

You also need to do same procedure on worker node kubelet.conf should have `--hostname-override` and the join command should have `--node-name`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the hostname. localhost as hostname wouldnt work in cluster.
correct the hostname with unique name.

Comment: How to set `hostname` when I run  `kubectl init`. It is OK to use ` --node-name=SOMETHING`?

Comment: I run `kubectl init` using `--node-name=xxxx`, it is not OK too